# How to insert blank pages at the beginning or at the end of a document without altering page number in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I'd like to add one or more cover pages before the text I already have.

I also want to insert blank pages (= without page number) at the end.

I don't want the page numbering to be altered in any case.

There's some funcion that seems to do the job: **Format - Title page**. I've tried changing many options but the funcion seems quite buggy: it's not clear what the options are for and I never get the result I want. I usually get a blank page and numbering starts by "2" on the next page. It should be "1".

Answer (score 2):

To **add a blank page at the beginning of the document**:

Go to the beginning of the document. Click: Insert – Manual break – Page break – Style: Default – Change page number: 1 – OK

Then go to the first page. Open "Styles and Formatting" window (press F11) – Page styles (4th button) – Double click on First Page

To add **one more blank page** at the beginning of the document:

Go to the end of the last blank page at the beginning of the document. Click: Insert – Manual break – Page break – Style: First page – OK

To **add a blank page at the end of the document**:

Go to the end of the document. Click: Insert – Manual break – Page break – Style: First page – Change page number : 0 – OK